# What types of discontinuities are present at these special discontinuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis

I am aware of the three different types of discontinuities:

1. Removable Discontinuity: where the limits of both sides exist and are equal but does not equal the value at that point
2. Jump Discontinuity: where the limits of both sides exist but are not equal
3. Mixed Discontinuity: where one of the limit sides does not exist

So the functions in question are the Dirichlet and Thomae's Functions. I think I know that the Dirichlet function is type 3 as one side of the limit exists and the other does not for all rational and irrational points. However, for Thomae's Function, I am a little confused because I think it is jump discontinuity but it gets very confusing when the range gets very close to 0 which seems to show behavior similar to Dirichlet but also not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function is discontinuous for all rational numbers, which results in problems with interpreting and working with the function. However, the limit there is zero. That means those points are removable discontinuities, which makes the popcorn function (weirdly) a continuous function, even though it isn’t intuitively so.[image]

Comment: Oh ok I think it makes sense but I still need time to process it. Thank you!